# PHP: How to save newly converted ffmpeg file into a temporary file

Tags: php

Iam trying to convert a video file to an audio, then save it as a temporary file without getting into my system / project directory  in PHP using ffmpeg 

`exec('ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn -ab 256 audio.mp3');`

please some one should help me out

I want `audio.mp3` to be saved into `tmpfile()` so that i can use the file without saving it into my project directory

Below is what I have tried 

`exec('ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn -ab 256 '.sys_get_temp_dir.'/audio.mp3')`

that worked but the whole file saved into my system temporary folder as an audio file not as a tmp file

Comment: Please show some code - what you have tried - that way we can help you!

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I have updated the post with what I have tried

Comment: Maybe take a look at passthru() to output the raw data instead of exec(). https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Comment: I'm not sure I do understand. You say you want your audio-file to be saved into tmpfile() but your exec files saves your mp4 into sys_get_temp_dir / audio.mp3. Just rename the .mp3 to .tmp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can as @bestprogrammerintheworld points out just save the file as .tmp, and then remove it when you don't need it anymore. (which is what `tmpfile` does anyway)

If you want to keep the file in memory you can use a pipe to write to an output

`exec('ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn -ab 256 -', $output, $return_var);`

where `-` is writing to to stdout, which will end up in the `$output`, which you then can write to a tmpfile if you'd want

Comment: ok, i have done exactly this in my system but ffmpeg is not executing on my linux server side please what could be wrong ?

Comment: No i did not get any error, this is actually my first time of using ffmpeg, so i dont really know how to implement it at the server side, my previous research helped me to understand that i need to create a `usr/bin` folder and extract my ffmpeg file in there but it did not work for me

Comment: @ AlexVestin I developed my app with a window pc i ran the the full script on my local machine and every thing was good now time to deploy, then noticed my hosting company runs a linux OS now i dont know how to go about deploying my app anymore, I have tried everything my hands can get on nothing seems to work,  if you can help me on step by step on how to (from installation in my webserver ) i will really appreciate just a clue will help thanks

Comment: You likely wil not have to change a lot, have you tried installing the required packages and running the program?